# What does the . mean in CSS?

Tags: css, syntax

I've read several tutorials on CSS, but none of the sites I've looked at mentions or explains what a "." means in CSS.

What does the . mean?

Comment: So why did you not read what it meant on that site?

Comment: @leppie - he probably meant "not one" instead of "on one".

Comment: @Franci Penov: I can hardly believe not a single site explained it. It is one of the primitive concepts of CSS.

Comment: @leppie - I agree with you. that does not preclude that the OP just had a poor google-fu day.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing without context.

I'll hazard a guess that you are referring to [a class selector](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the following context:

```
.foo {
   //properties
}
```

it indicates that foo is a class. A # means it's an id and if it has nothing it means that it is for all tags of that type. So, in html, you would implement something with a "." like this:

```
<div class = "foo"></div>
```

For a "#" it would be

```
<div id = "foo"></div>
```

Use class/"." if you want to apply it to more than one thing. Use id/"#" if you want it to apply to one thing.

Ok, so if your wondering what a class is:
A class is one of the three (I think it's 3) types of ways you select stuff in css. The id (which I explained) says that the following properties apply to anything (usually one thing) with 'id="foo"' in its tag. A class selector means that it applies to everything with a "class="foo"" in its tag. If it has none of these than it means that it applies to all things with that name.

```
.foo { //applies to all things with "class="foo"" in tag.
    border: black thin solid // applies a black border to them.
}
#foo { //applies to all things with "id="foo"" in tag.
    border: black thin solid // applies a black border to them.
}
div{ //applies to all div tags.
    border: black thin solid // applies a black border to them.
}
h1{ //applies to all h1 tags
    border: black thin solid // applies a black border to them.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html). Means the rule should be applied to all elements that have an attribute `class` with the value after the `.`.

Comment: See http://w3fools.com/ — As usual there are errors here. "In the example below, all p elements with class="center" will be center-aligned:" isn't true. `text-align` doesn't centre the element to which it is applied, it centres the inline and text children of that element.

Comment: Yes, the w3schools do have some mistakes.